# How to match regular expression for lines there is just one number and all words vice versa?

Tags: regex

I have some words how can i match regular expression just one number and all words vice versa?

```
YV932X6R
V5R67HD1
5R3XPD61
57342D61
CRHXPDV2
12345678
CDHKPQRV
```

I've tried to use this way, but it's not quite what I want

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

**Output**

```
YV932X6R
V5R67HD1
5R3XPD61
57342D61
CRHXPDV2
```

**Expected Output**

```
CRHXPDV2
```

OR

```
57342D61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the length, then you may use the following patterns for just one number or just one letter:

```regex
^[A-Za-z]*[0-9][A-Za-z]*$
^[0-9]*[A-Za-z][0-9]*$
```

If you also have a length requirement of 8 characters, you could enforce that via a positive lookahead.  For example, the pattern for one digit and the rest letters would become:

```regex
^(?=.{8}$)[A-Za-z]*[0-9][A-Za-z]*$
```

Comment: oh i see, thanks. It's Work like what i want